# Super-s: How to express it? Is some escaping needed in the syntax?

Tags: key-bindings, modifier-key

This code binds "Super-c" to lambda:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "s-c")
      (lambda () (interactive) (jump-to-register 'q)))
```

How can I bind Super-s? They are both denoted as "s": `(kbd "s-s")`. I need to escape one of them somehow.

My Emacs version: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, i586-slackware-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2019-08-29. Running on Linux Slackware 14.2.

Answer (score 3):

`(kbd "s-s")` works just fine for me.  Verified in both 27.1 and 26.3.

I *suspect* your window manager is capturing this sequence, and Emacs never sees it at all.

What does typing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>s-s</kbd> tell you?

If Emacs doesn't register the <kbd>s-s</kbd>, then I think you'll find that never actually reached Emacs, and you should start looking at your window manager's keybindings.

Comment: Typing `C-h k s-s` shows nothing. I'll check the window manager.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try just `(kbd "s-s")`? Does that not work? (I don't have a <kbd>Super</kbd> key, so I can't check.)

There should be no problem with the two `s` occurrences meaning different things. As a *modifier*, `s-` is realized by the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

But it's a good question, considering that you can also define plain `s` as a *prefix key*, in which case, for example, you could have the key sequence `s s`, which would be the prefix key `s` followed by `s` (same key). That's different from `s-s`, however.

---

**UPDATE**

The Emacs manual [Glossary](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Glossary.html) says this about a Super key:

> Super is the name of a modifier bit that a keyboard input character may have. To make a character Super, type it while holding down the `<SUPER>` key. Such characters are given names that start with `Super-` (usually written `s-` for short). See Modifier Keys.

So maybe try `(kbd "Super-s")`. Or even (I doubt it) `(kbd "<SUPER>-s")`.

And the Elisp manual, node [Other Char Bits](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Other-Char-Bits.html) says:

> The X Window System defines three other modifier bits that can be set
> in a character: “hyper”, “super” and “alt”.  The syntaxes for these bits
> are `\H-`, `\s-` and `\A-`.  (Case is significant in these prefixes.)
> Thus, `?\H-\M-\A-x` represents `Alt-Hyper-Meta-x`.  (Note that `\s` with
> no following `-` represents the space character.)  Numerically, the bit
> values are 2**22 for alt, 2**23 for super and 2**24 for hyper.

So maybe try `[?\s-s]`? E.g. `(global-set-key [?\s-s] 'forward-word)`

Comment: "Did you try just `(kbd "s-s")`? Does that not work?" - I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: Odd, seems that it's impossible to create a keybinding: "Super - s".

Comment: What key is supposed to be the Super key? It may be that the key  is hijacked be the DE so emacs never sees it. That's what happens in Gnome e.g. where the Windoze key is supposed to be the Super key, but is used by the DE for various tasks.

Comment: @NickD: No idea. Haven't used a Lisp machine in a long time... ;-)

Comment: `(global-set-key [?\s-s] 'forward-word)` - doesn't work. Seems, that Super-s combo is being captured by KDE.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it -- I'm using a generic example because I don't have any prior experience playing with the function `jump-to-register`:

```lisp
(define-key global-map [?\s-s] (lambda () (interactive) (message "hello-world")))
```

Comment: It sounds strange, but it doesn't work. Maybe, it's a limitation of Emacs?

Comment: I can assure you that the code in the answer above works 100% in GUI versions of Emacs, built `--with-ns`, using either Emacs 25,  Emacs 26, or Emacs 27 on an Apple/Mac computer.  I just tested it on all three (3) of the above-mentioned public releases -- testing without any user-configuration, aka `emacs -Q`

Comment: My Emacs is this: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, i586-slackware-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.18.9) of 2019-08-29. Seems ok. Launched emacs -Q, tried your code, but it still doesn't work: no message in the minibuffer.

Comment: Ah ... Please add that information to your question by editing the question so that everyone knows you're running on a Linux machine and the Emacs version information, etc.